# selector in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm beginner in Javascript. I have a list of links and I want to select links end with .zip and add class zip from css;

add select links end with not .zip and add class notzip from css.

I use 
`$("a[href $='.zip']").addClass("zip")` to do the first task but cannot do the task 2 by add ! or not(). It is recommended by $this and location, filter function.  How can I do that?

```
      <ul>
    <li><a href="a.html">a</a></li>
    <li><a href="b.pdf">b</a></li>
    <li><a href="c.zip">c</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [`:not`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```js
$(function() {
  $("a[href$='.zip']").addClass('zip');
  $("a:not([href$='.zip'])").addClass('notzip');
  $("a:not([href$='.zip']):not([href$='.html'])").addClass('notzipnorhtml');
  
  var exts = ['html', 'pdf', 'zip'];
  $('a' + exts.map(ext => ':not([href$=".' + ext + '"])').join(''))
    .addClass('notanyofthose');
});
```

```css
.zip { color: green; }
.notzip { color: red; }
.notzipnorhtml { color: purple; }
.notanyofthose { color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="a.html">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="b.pdf">b</a></li>
  <li><a href="c.zip">c</a></li>
  <li><a href="d.exe">d</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Seems like the problem appears in logic part when I used "not" before.  `$("a:not([href$='.zip'])").addClass('notzip');` covers  the result of `$("a[href$='.zip']").addClass('zip');` when adding class 'notzip' to href that doesn't suffix with .zip or .html. Why it happens?

Comment: @JiayanYang I don't understand your question. Can you show how you used `:not` in your case, to see what might've been wrong?

Comment: @JetoThe `:not` works well. However when I `$("a:not([href$='.zip||.html)'])").addClass("download");` , the results cover the `$("a[href$='.zip']").addClass('zip');`. In your example the green also becomes red.

Comment: `$("a:not([href$='.zip||.html)'])")` is not correct. What are you trying to achieve? You want to match anything that doesn't end with either .zip or .html?

Comment: @JetoExactly. Want to find anything except href ends with .zip or .html. This is why I said 'Seems like the problem appears in logic part when I used "not()" before.' Sorry for my poor English:)

Comment: I've added a `.notzipnorhtml` example in my code. Now obviously the second `<li>` will have both CSS classes, so the last rule will take precedence.

Comment: Thanks! Now it is what I want. However is there any way to express `"a:not([href$='.zip']):not([href$='.html'])"`? Now I have two limits, what if more?

Comment: Added another example with an array of extensions this time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly,
this should work!

```
$("a[href='.zip']").addClass("zip");
$("a[href!='.zip']").addClass("notzip");
```

Comment: @testingKikiHi thanks for your advice. I think `href='.zip'` should be `href $= '.zip'`  since I need to add class for href end with .zip. :)